# jqGrid cannot inline edit

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework, jqgrid

I have been searching all over internet for a solution to my simple problem (I hope) but unfortunately nothing has helped!..

I am a beginner with jqGrid and I have successfully made it to show all my sample array data in a table.. What I want is to be able to edit the "role" column inline and save it back to the array data... I am using Zend framework and have this issue:

My problems

I am not able to edit the data at all. I can just select and highlight as usual, no textarea is been provided..

Here is my HTML (please verify I am using the right libraries):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>JqGrid Test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/js/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />  
    <script src="/js/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/test/index.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="/js/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>      
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"  class="scroll"></table>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Next my `index.js`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastsel2;
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        colNames:['Role Id','name'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", editable: true},           
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, sortable:false,editable: true,
                edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10" },     
        ],
        onSelectRow: function(id){
            if(id && id!==lastsel2){
                jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel2);
                jQuery('#list').editRow(id,true);
                lastsel2=id;
            }
        },
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
    });
    var mydata = [  
            {id:"1",name:"test"},
            {id:"2",name:"test2"},
            {id:"3",name:"test3"},
            {id:"4",name:"test"},
            {id:"5",name:"test2"},
            {id:"6",name:"test3"},
            {id:"7",name:"test"},
            {id:"8",name:"test2"},
            {id:"9",name:"test3"}
        ];
    for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
});
```

What am I missing? I hope my question was clear and I thank and appreciate in adv to all who posts a response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many errors in the code which you posted.

- You should never use `<html>` without `<!DOCTYPE html ...`. It means [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) of HTML. The later HTML code looks like XHTML. So you should use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

- You should include only **one** version of any JavaScript library. In your code you included first jQuery 1.8.2 (it was error in `src` attribute too. it should be `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"`) and then included `jquery-1.7.2.min.js`. In the same way you included first `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and then included `grid.loader.js` which will include the same jqGrid code, but non-minimized.
- The next point is not an real error, but you can remove `class="scroll"` which are not used by jqGrid since many many versions.
- The definition of `'name'` column contain syntax error: you have to include `}` at the end of the definition of `'name'` column.
- You use `for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)` instead of `for(var i=0;i<mydata.length;i++)`. The usage of `addRowData` for the filling of grid is bad and slowly. You should just move the code which defines `mydata` before the code which create jqGrid and add `data: mydata` as additional parameter.
- If you want to implement *local* editing of data you have to add additional parameter `editurl: "clientArray"` to the grid.

The next problem was the main reason why I wrote my answer. The problem is that you defined editable column `'id'` in the grid. The problem is that jqGrid uses internally `"id"` as the `id` attribute of the row (`<tr>` elements) known as the rowid too. So you should *rename* `id` column to another name. Additionally you should provide `id` attribute in the input data which will be used as the rowid.

If you do prefer to hold your original `"id"` name for the column with the custom data and want that jqGrid uses any other property name like `"id1"` for example as the rowid you have to include

```js
localReader: {id: "id1"}, // needed for reading of the rowids
prmNames: {id: "id1"}     // needed for editing
```

In the case `mydata` could looks like

```js
var mydata = [
        {id: "1", id1: "10", name: "test"},
        {id: "2", id1: "20", name: "test2"},
        {id: "3", id1: "30", name: "test3"},
        {id: "4", id1: "40", name: "test"},
        {id: "5", id1: "50", name: "test2"},
        {id: "6", id1: "60", name: "test3"},
        {id: "7", id1: "70", name: "test"},
        {id: "8", id1: "80", name: "test2"},
        {id: "9", id1: "90", name: "test3"}
    ];
```

[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/1291.htm) you will see the demo which is fixing of your original code. It uses values "10", "20", ..., "90" (`id1`) as the rowids (values of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements) and it uses `id` with your custom data which can be edited.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I understand my mistakes and thank you again for editing my code as well. Yesterday I looked through my jqGrid libraries and found that I forgot to include "jquery.jqGrid.src.js", after which everything was functional. Thanks again!

Comment: @1291: You are welcome! The code which you posted already contains `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` which is the minimized version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. So you should include **one** from the following files: 1) `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` 2) `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` 3) `grid.loader.js`. The file `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`  is concatenation of the files included in `grid.loader.js` with exception of `grid.locale-en.js`.