# How to add new row record in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am use jqGrid. I want to add record inline navigation
so this link http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html?
when i click in ADD new row icon in navbar. Grid is like view modal view.

```html
<div id="pager"></div>
<table id="ward"></table>
<br />
<script src="js/rowedex3.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#ward").jqGrid({
    mtype : 'GET',
    url : "listAllWards.html",
    datatype : "json",
    colNames : [ 'Id', 'Ward Type', 'Description'],
    colModel : [ {
        name : 'id',
        index : 'id',
        editable:true,
        width : 50
    }, {
        name : 'name',
        index : 'name',
        width : 150,
        editable:true,
    }, {
        name : 'decsription',
        index : 'decsription',
        width : 100,
        editable:true,
    }],
    rowNum : 5,
    rowList : [ 5, 10, 30 ],
    pager : '#pager',
    sortname : 'id',
    viewrecords : true,
    sortorder : "desc",
    caption : "Ward's List",
    width : 940,
    cellEdit : true,
    editurl: "server.html",
});
jQuery("#ward").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    edit : false,
    del : false,
    search :false,
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use inline editing for add the row you should use `add: false` option of `navGrid` (together with `edit: false` which you already use) and you should include call of [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) after calling of `navGrid`. You can choose the buttons added by `inlineNav` by the usage of corresponding options of `inlineNav` described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav).

**UPDATED**: You have to remove `cellEdit : true` option from jqGrid because the usage of both cell editing and inline editing is not supported.

Additionally you have to rename `id` column to any other name if you need to edit the grid. See the second part on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12960864/315935) for additional details.

I recommend you to place the whole JavaScript code inside of `$(function(){...});` and move it inside of `<head>`.

You should verify that you use current (now 4.4.1) version of jqGrid.

Comment: I want add:true on these icon i want add new row so it keep false or true

Comment: if My Code is these
jQuery("#room").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', {
edit : false,
del : false,
search :false,
});   jQuery("#room").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager2",parameters);
when i select Plus sign my grid view is like modal view means Grid is Total Selected

Comment: @AshuMehta: `navGrid` add buttons which creates forms ("modal view") instead of `inlineNav` which implements the same operation *inline*. Do you tried `inlineNav`?

Comment: My Code is
jQuery("#ward").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{edit:false,del:false});
jQuery("#ward").jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager',{
add: true,
addicon:"ui-icon-plus",
});

Comment: I want add Plus Sign Icon So I Add now on Click Plus Icon Add New Row But Grid View Is Selected.So what do so i can add new blank row in grid

Comment: @AshuMehta: Like I wrote before you need add `add: false` to the list of options of `navGrid` if you don't want add row per form editing. The default options of `inlineNav` will add "+" which work like you need (`jQuery("#ward").jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager')`)

Comment: as per link add Plus icon add new row   link..http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html How it possible...

Comment: @AshuMehta: I am tired to repeat the same thing: the code `jQuery("#ward").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{add:false,edit:false,del:false}); jQuery("#ward").jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager');` adds the "+" icon which do what you need. If you need to have less *other* icons you can use the corresponding options of `inlineNav` or `navGrid`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18580/discussion-between-ashumehta-and-oleg)